# Restructuring HTML in PHP (Simple HTML DOM Parser)

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I would like to create a program that converts the body part of a HTML code like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TestA</h1>
        <table class="board">
            <tr>
                <td class="other" id="field20">TestB</td>
                <td class="testclass" id="field21">TestC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="testclass">TestD</td>
                <td class="testclass">TestE</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

into something like this:

```
h1 with: 'TestA'.
table class: 'board'; with: [
    tr with: [
        td class: 'other'; id: 'field20'; with: 'TestB'.
        td class: 'testclass'; id: 'field21'; with: 'TestC'.
    ].
    tr with: [
        td class: 'testclass'; with: 'TestD'.
        td class: 'testclass'; with: 'TestE'.
    ].
].
```

Therefore I obviously got to iterate through all the HTML tags with it's content, it's attributes and attributevalues, respecting it's node level.
To achieve that, I guess I need the HTML DOM Parser, but I didn't find a way to really iterate through the tags, the way I would need it to.
So if anybody could help me with that (maybe there is a complete different way to manage this), that would be awesome!!!

Comment: You need ext/dom, but not a special PHP library. You're going to iterate each node anyway so abstraction will not help you. I suggest writing a function that outputs a DOMElement instances nodeName, attributes and calls itself for each child element.